# HttpWebRequest "Put" verb behaviour in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, webdav, http-put

I am trying to understand the dialogue flow between my just written webdav client app and an IIS server. Actually, I need to understand it as it does work with https but not with normal http and the servers are configured to accept both.

First, "PROPFIND" seems to work well. The funny thing though is that if I analyze the HTTP traffic with Fiddler, there is a 401 response from the server that my program does not see... I try then the same operation with Windows Mini-redirector and the same happens. There is a 401 response there that does not seem to affect. This is with http.

Then, the next step is to send a file with "PUT" in a HttpWebRequest. My application does not throw any error and does not even get any response, it just waits for it indefinitely, which, to the effect, is like freezing; however, in Fiddler, or other network analyzer, there is a 401 response from the server that my app seems to miss and there is no more traffic after.
I try then with mini-redirector and the same 401 is there but there is a following 201 response and the file is uploaded.

All seems to work well with https in my app. I have tried with IIS 6.0 IIS 7 and IIS 8.0. Them all are configured to accept non SSL traffic.

Can someone enlighten me as why is that 401 there that my app does not see? It is also in the traffic with mini-redirector but doesn't seem to bother.

Also, any experience on why it would not work with http, mini-redirector does so the server accepts it, but would work with https?

Comment: I have found a detail difference in the frames from mini-redirector and myapp. In the request, in the mini-redir frame there is a last line as follow: WebDav: Request, PUT /... which isn't in the frames of my app (the hex details in netmon does not show anything though); thus, the protocol in netmon shows as webdav for mini-redir and http for my app. I guess the server than understands them differently. Any help...?

Comment: Well, seems like the missing 401 response is a challenge from the server to negotiate authentication and it is normal in any request dialogue. There are also some responses 'continue'. These responses are ignored as exceptions by the HttpWebRequest method; as it should be. However, I still don't get it to work on http. The program just waits and waits... The differences between the frame produced by HttpWebRequest and mini-redir is the last line "WebDav: Request... Please, any idea how I can make this happen in my app?

Comment: Right. I have not found why it does not work but I have coded again the function using XMLHTTPClass from MSXML COM and it works perfectly. I am using the same credentials to the same servers. There is something fishy with HttpWebRequest.

Comment: One more comment that might help someone in the future with this. I don't have a solution for the problem I am experienceing with HttpWebRequest (perhaps someone with experience could help here) but note that using XMLHTTPClass only works with http by design. If you need to use also https then ServerXMLHTTPClass is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote IIS didn't like the option SendChunked = true. It seems that it does not like unknown sizes. The code with HttpWebRequest method had this option. Without it, it works just fine.